# Unable to mount Azure Data Lake Storage Gen 2 with Azure Databricks

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-storage, databricks, azure-databricks

I try to mount an Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 account using a service principal and OAuth 2.0 as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/azure-datalake-gen2#--mount-an-azure-data-lake-storage-gen2-account-using-a-service-principal-and-oauth-20):

```py
configs = {
  "fs.azure.account.auth.type": "OAuth",
  "fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type": "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider",
  "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id": "<application-id>",
  "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret": dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "<scope-name>", key = "<key-name-for-service-credential>"),
  "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<directory-id>/oauth2/token"}

dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "abfss://<file-system-name>@<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/",
  mount_point = "/mnt/<mount-name>",
  extra_configs = configs
)
```

The service principal that I use has the `Storage Blob Data Contributor` role at the storage account level and has also `rwx` access at the container level.

Anyway, I get this error:

```
ExecutionError: An error occurred while calling o242.mount.
: HEAD https://<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<file-system-name>?resource=filesystem&timeout=90
StatusCode=403
StatusDescription=This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
```

I even tried to access it directly using the storage account access key as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/azure-datalake-gen2#--access-directly-using-the-storage-account-access-key) but without success:

```py
spark.conf.set(
  "fs.azure.account.key.<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net",
  dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "<scope-name>", key = "<key-name-for-service-credential>")
)
dbutils.fs.ls("abfss://<file-system-name>@<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<directory-name>")
```

The thing is that with the Azure CLI I have no problem interacting with this storage account:

```sh
az login --service-principal --username <application-id> --tenant <directory-id>
az storage container list --account-name <storage-account-name> --auth-mode login
```

Also, no problem using the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/filesystem/getproperties) on my machine but I get a `AuthorizationFailure` once on the cluster:

```py
from getpass import getpass

import requests

from msal import ConfidentialClientApplication

client_id = "<application-id>"
client_password = getpass()

authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<directory-id>"
scope = ["https://storage.azure.com/.default"]

app = ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id, authority=authority, client_credential=client_password
)

tokens = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scope)
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + tokens["access_token"],
    "x-ms-version": "2019-07-07" # THIS IS REQUIRED OTHERWISE I GET A 400 RESPONSE
}


endpoint = (
    "https://<account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<filesystem>//?action=getAccessControl"
)
response = requests.head(endpoint, headers=headers)

print(response.headers)
```

The firewall is set to only allow trusted Microsoft services to access the storage account.

Did I entered a black hole or is anybody experiencing the same issue with Databricks ? Is it caused by the ABFS driver ?

Comment: Please do checkout the answer on MSDN thread: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7c8d58a4-04d1-4d0a-a9fa-c48c9991f1ab/azure-databricks-throwing-403-error?forum=AzureDatabricks

Comment: @CHEEKATLAPRADEEP-MSFT Am I missing something from the thread because I already did what's in it ?

Comment: Databricks is not (yet) a Trusted Microsoft Services. You may try to add Databricks to the IAM ? Or maybe create a vnet that would include databricks and provide you with an IP that you could whitelist ? Have a look here : https://databricks.com/blog/2020/02/28/securely-accessing-azure-data-sources-from-azure-databricks.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the problem was due to the firewall settings. Thank you Axel R!

I was misled by the fact that I also have a ADLS Gen 1 with the same firewall settings and had no problem.

BUT, the devil is in the details. The Gen 1 firewall exceptions allow **all** Azure services to access the resource. The Gen 2, meanwhile, only allows **trusted** Azure services.

I hope this can help someone.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer. You can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: The latest Gen 1 storage accounts firewall also only allow trusted MS services which don't include Azure Databricks.

Comment: I am facing similar problem. Where exactly we setup firewall exception to access resources from Azure DataBricks?